# linking libraries under Linux

Tags: linux, opencv, ld

I experienced a (for me) strange behaviour today: Using QMake with the PkgConfig-options etc. I was able to link the opencv libraries, but then I switched to CMake using PkgConfig. Once I tried to build my software, the linker complained that it was not able to find the library `libcvaux`, which pkg-config returns asked to deliver the libraries for `opencv` (`pkg-config --libs opencv`).

In `/usr/lib` I found a `libcvaux.so.{version}`, but no "plain" entry `libcvaux.so`. So what I did was to create a symlink, and now it works.

Now I wonder why it worked before. Is there something to pass `ld` an option saying "use the newest version, and you get the version by looking at the numbers behind the `so` suffix"? Or is it more some kind of bug that the maintainers of the opencv package forgot to add this symlink? Because e.g. `libcv` or `libhighgui` have such symbolic links.

Thank you!

Comment: MOve to serverfault please, or superuser.

Comment: nothing in this question relevant to c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ldconfig manpage:

> ldconfig checks the header and file
>   names of the libraries it encounters
>   when determining which versions should
>   have their links updated.

Maybe an earlier ldconfig run deleted the link.

Comment: Thank you for this aswer, I wasn't aware of `ldconfig`. Anyway, I ran it, it didn't solve my problem. For the lib I mentioned, it just creates a symlink `version.subsersion -> version.subversion.patchlevel`. This is different to the way `libcv` is treated, there I find the symlinks I would expect for `libcvaux`. I take the pragmatic way of sticking with my symlink and try to keep in mind that `ldconfig` maintains them for all the other libraries.